# where to download javaee.jar with entire method bodies

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

i installed glassfish and in the lib i found javaee.jar 
but including it in the classpath does not help.

It gives me the error that the transactionManager class is not found .whereas if i use javaee-api.jar it gives the error Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class  .plz help:(

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.createDb(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:47)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.main(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:38) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.TransactionManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.createDb(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:47)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.main(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:38)
at __SHELL0.run(__SHELL0.java:6)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)
```

this is the file which i got

```
-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-     instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"><modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>-<parent><groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId><artifactId>javaee-pom</artifactId><version>4.0</version></parent><name>GlassFish javaee.jar </name><artifactId>javaee</artifactId>-<build>-<plugins>-<plugin><artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>-<configuration>-<archive>-<manifestEntries><Class-Path>../modules/javax.servlet-api.jar ../modules/endorsed/javax.annotation-api.jar .   ./modules/javax.ejb-api.jar ../modules/javax.transaction-api.jar ../modules/javax.enterprise.deploy-api.jar ../modules/javax.management.j2ee-api.jar ../modules/javax.resource-api.jar ../modules/javax.security.auth.message-api.jar ../modules/javax.security.jacc-api.jar ../modules/webservices-osgi.jar ../modules/jaxb-osgi.jar ../modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar ../modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar ../modules/javax.xml.rpc-api.jar ../modules/javax.xml.registry-api.jar ../modules/javax.mail.jar ../modules/javax.faces.jar ../modules/javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar ../modules/javax.el.jar ../modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar ../modules/javax.persistence.jar ../modules/javax.jms-api.jar ../modules/bean-validator.jar ../modules/weld-osgi-bundle.jar ../../mq/lib/jaxm-api.jar ../modules/javax.ws.rs-api.jar ../modules/javax.json.jar ../modules/javax.websocket-api.jar ../modules/javax.enterprise.concurrent-api.jar ../modules/javax.batch-api.jar</Class-Path><GlassFish-ServerExcluded>true</GlassFish-ServerExclu   ded></manifestEntries></archive></configuration></plugin></plugins></build></project>
```

Comment: have u check that class exist in javaee.jar ?

Comment: open the javee.jar which decompiler

Comment: sorry,i opened it with jar decompiler and the only file i could see is pom.xml amd pom.properties .. I cannot see any classes. can ypu please help me with where can i get a javaee.jar file with entire body

Answer (score 1):

Try including

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

this dependency in your pom.xml

Comment: i added this dependendency but it still give me the following error "java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/transaction/SystemException
"  .